# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$refs') vue js

Tags: vue.js, input, hook, refs

Getting the Error *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$refs')* though I'm having a reference in the template. Does it mean I must use Vue mounted hook ?

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
   <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" ref="input"/>
</div>
                            
<script>                   
  this.$refs.input.addEventListener('input', function () {
        // some code
 });
</script>
```

Comment: The component wasn't defined at all here. `this` is undefined or window in script context. You need to access `this` at least in some hook or method. Element ref is supposed to be accessed in mounted hook or later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside root of `<script>` of a Vue component, in both Vue 2 and Vue 3, `this` is `undefined`:

```html
<script>
  console.log(this) // undefined
</script>
```

See it [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9jssKgzAQRX8lzKoFTfYSCv2PbKxONWIezES7EP+9SSlSWuhu7oMzd4NrjHJdEBrQ3JGN6WJ8FzyHGeUchlMaLZ+N1+pIs0jo4twmzEoI3dtVqHxqdfhQgXUxUKpdG+XEwecHW2mbd8AGGvFyipcXFG1gTClyoxTfuzJrYhloUPmStPhkHUpkV98oPBgpgw1UHwyVzRWpJvQ9EtI/5lf1h1uwu/E77E9rw2Zb).

---

Vue [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) can only be accessed inside any hook or method happening after the component has been mounted and before it is unmounted.

Which means ***the earliest*** you can reference `this.$refs` is inside [mounted](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted). And ***the latest*** is in [beforeUnmount](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#beforeunmount). And you can also access them in any hook or method happening between those two moments.

---

Considering you're attempting to add an event listener to a HTMLInputElement, I'd recommend using the [v-on](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on) directive, which automatically adds the event listener on mount and removes it on unmount.

In your case:

```html
<template>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input 
      type="text"
      id="phone"
      placeholder="(555) 555-5555"
      @input="myFn" />
  </div>
</template>
                            
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    myFn(event) {
      console.log(event)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

As a side note, you should know that a regular function's `this` doesn't have access to the component context, unless it's an arrow function:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      /*
       * Here `this` is the context of the current function, you can't 
       * access methods, computed, data or props of the component.
       * You'd need to make it an arrow function to access the component scope
       */
    })
  }
}
```

Whereas in any method (e.g: the above `myFn`), `this` is the component context, which has access to all component members.

Comment: Highly appriciate, could you show how the refs with computed hook logic would look in my case please ?

Comment: Assuming I need to wrap this. $refs…. inside a body of an arrow function

Comment: It's the last snippet I added, except the function would change from `function(){/* this is function context }` to `() => { /* this is component context */ }`.